# Простое ограничение ввода

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Конструкцией, написанной ниже, можно ограничить ввод некоторых символов в поле для ввода на форме. Главный плюс - простота. Главный минус - можно вставить букву через ctrl+V

```
<input type="text" onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.replace (/\D/, '')">
```

1. Как запретить вставку через ctrl+v?
2. Как не ограничивать ввод, а сделать доступным только определенные символы? Скажем, только цифры, или только буквы, или цифры+буквы+знаки препинания?

if ( если кто ответит ) { заранее благодарю }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Замените `/\D/` на `/\D/g` - будет убирать все буквы, а не одну.
2. Только вашим способом + аналогичной проверкой на стороне сервера.

Comment: ок. понял.

Answer (score 1):

Идея правильная, но во-первых, на keyUp такие вещи ставить не совсем правильно по отношению к пользователю - у него будет появляться и исчезать буквы - а во-вторых такой конструкцией Вы не запрещаете что-то вводить, а только модифицируете уже введенное значение.

Мой вариант (для ввода только цифр) - справляется и с ctrl+V =)

```
//ПРОВЕРКА ВВОДА ЧИСЛОВОГО ЗНАЧЕНИЯ//
function chk_int_value(event)
{
    var list=new Array (8,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106);

    var i;
    for(i=0;i<list.length;i++)
    {
        if(list[i]==event.keyCode) 
        {
            return true;    
        }
    };
    return false;
}
$('#id').keydown(function(event){
    return chk_int_value(event);
});
```